# Gravitational energy and its conservation in quantum field theory

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How does conservation of energy in quantum field theories reconcile with gravitational energy that is not modeled with quantum field theories? Does this mean that conservation of energy is only approximate in quantum field theories and does this change the foundations of the theories which assume symmetries to drive metric conservation?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the gravitational potential as an external field in any QFT.  For any QFT you want, you can always just add the term $\phi \rho$ where $\phi$ is a gravitational potential, and $\rho$ is the mass density of your QFT, and then you simply do not vary $\phi$ when varying your Lagrangian.

Various special spacetimes (in particular, those with timelike killing vectors) let you define local gravitational potentials in full general relativity as well, and you can apply a similar trick.  If you wind up doing something like "well, this gravitational potential creates a new mass distribution, and that mass distribution should gravitate, let's see the corrections" to find a new spacetime, you are starting to do what is called "semi-classical gravity," and it is very similar to the sort of thing that was done in early quantum mechanics before we knew how to quantize the electromagnetic field, and there are whole books on making this work.

Comment: Thanks - I understand how perturbation can apply gravity field to QFT, and also conservation of energy as a consequence of killing vectors time symmetry in GR. I was trying to understand how QFT energy conservation which doesn’t include gravity would still be a correct conservation rule. On reflection I guess this is because we haven’t incorporated a graviton into the standard model yet - and doing this needs to change both the fields and the shape of the space time.